# Setup loops: never enters loop - restarting?

Tags: wire-library, arduino-uno-wifi

I uploaded the following to my UNO with WiFi:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_CCS811.h"
      
Adafruit_CCS811 ccs; // The air quality sensor
    
String Dataline = ""; 

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();

  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.println("SET UP");
}

void loop() {
  // wait a second between measurements.
  delay(1000);

  Dataline = "";
  Dataline = Dataline + getTime();
  Dataline = Dataline + AIRSensor();
  Dataline = Dataline + "...";
  Serial.println(Dataline); 
}

String getTime() {
  String OUT = "Tim::";
  OUT += String(millis());
  return OUT;
}

String AIRSensor() {
  if (ccs.available()) {
    if (!ccs.readData()) {
      float temp = ccs.calculateTemperature();
      String CO2 = (String)ccs.geteCO2();
      return "CO2::" + CO2 +"TAQ::" + (String)temp;
    }
  } else {
    return "CO2::-999,TAQ::-999";
  }
}
```

The output is simply "SET UP" repeated:

```
SET UP
SET UP
SET UP
...
```

It never enters the loop or prints anything else out. Does this mean the UNO is resetting? How do I troubleshoot?

Comment: how do you know that it does not enter `loop()`? ... you have no code that confirms that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell that something is going wrong between your `println`. Some advice in this case: eliminate the `String` entirely and replace the `println` with a series of `print`. This would let you narrow down which function is causing the problem. It also can save some memory, which is a nice bonus in embedded programming.

I suspect in this case the problem is your use of C-style casts to `String` in `AIRSensor()`. `(String)whatever` and `String(whatever)` do very different things, and the former is not something you want here, or something you should be using very often in C++ code.

The code in `loop` is running, but it is crashing and causing the hardware to reset. Since it is crashing before it reaches the first visible behavior in `loop`, it just looks like `setup` is running over and over.

Comment: Thanks! Changing from '(String)' to 'String()' made a massive difference. 
It now runs for about 6 loops, and then stops for a while. In the IDE, I get a 'Error while setting serial port parameters: 115,200 N 8 1' message. It then restarts again. 
Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: 'twas an issue with me not using 'ccs.begin()'. Thank you for your help!!